# Python Path Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, windows-xp

I am currently working with a Windows XP Computer at my school. My question is on how to find the exact path variable to run Python in the command line. I have tried multiple directories but they all keep displaying "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Is there an easy way to find this?

Comment: Usually it installs in C:\Python3X

Comment: for python-2.7 usual path is  C:\python27\ so you can open command prompt and do `cd C:\python27\` and run `python` now check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the installation is ok. You can use python, opening the command prompt window and navigating to your Python installation directory (default is `C:\Python27`). Type python from this location to launch the Python interpreter.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Username> cd C:\Python27

C:\Python27> python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Another way you can follow an Installation [tutorial](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation).

You can run Python from any location without having to constantly reference the full installation pathname.

This can be done by adding the Python installation path to Windows' `PATH` `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE`
**In Windows 7 and Windows 8, simply searching for "environment variables" will present the option to `Edit the system environment variables`. This will open the `System Properties / Advanced` tab*
**In Windows XP, right-click on `My Computer->Properties` to open `System Properties` and click on the `Advanced` tab.*

1. On the `System Properties / Advanced` tab, click `Environment Variables` to open `User Variables` and `System Variables`
2. Create a new `System Variable` named Variable name: `PYTHON_HOME` and  Variable value: `c:\Python27` (or whatever your installation path was)
   [image]
3. Find the system variable called `Path` and click `Edit`
   [image]
4. Add the following text to the end of the Variable value:  `;%PYTHON_HOME%\;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\`
   [image]
5. Verify a successful environment variable update by opening a new command prompt window (important!) and typing `python` from any location.

Comment: So would I have to use that directory every time or is there a way to add that to environment variables. Because I did try putting "C:\Python27" as the environment and it didn't work. Should I add quotations or just apply as written?

Comment: Don't add quotes. And you can add that to your path, but on a school computer I'm not sure you'd have permissions do to so.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use Python in any location adding it on the Windows system variables.