# New to Python. Question about running programs

Tags: python

Just dipped my toes into Python this morning and I'm trying to pare down how long of a directory I have to input to run my *.py programs.

My Python install directory is `C:\Python\Python39`

My work folder is `C:\python_work`

I made a file called `hello_world.py` and would like to run it directly from the `C:\python_work` folder, but it won't let me. It just returns `C:\python_work` instead of `"Hello Python World!"`.

The book I'm following says I should be able to type `C:\python_work>python hello_world.py`. That doesn't work. I have to type `C:\python_work>C:\Python\Python39\python hello_world.py`.

How do I get python to run directly from the `python_work` directory? I hope what I've written has made sense.

Thanks!

EDIT: PATH option is selected on install. Did that before coming here.

Comment: Just open your directory in terminal and type `python hello_world.py` . Also See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Path Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140580/python-path-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is that you do not have python added to your PATH.

You can add it to your PATH by using this set of instructions: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows.

Or you may want to uninstall and then reinstall python ensuring you check the add to PATH button in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you type `python --version` into your command line? If it returns an error, it likely means that you haven't added Python to your system path.

If you type *variables* into your windows search, you'll see the entry below. Click on that and add your python directory (`C:\Python\Python39\`) into the entry called *PATH*.

[image]

Once python is in your path, you should be able to open the python work directory and simply run it with the python command.

```
# in a new terminal

cd C:\python_work
python hello_world.py
```

Comment: Should I add the C:\python_work to PATH as well?

Comment: Only if you want to be able to call the scripts in there directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Write in command line: `python --version` the output must be some like:

> Python 3.8.5

If appers:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

You will need add Python to Windows Path variable [Add Python to the Windows Path](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/).

2. To execute your program, you can try with:

`> python C:\python_work\hello_world.py`

or:

`C:\python_work>python hello_world.py`

Answer (score -1):

That's because you do not have `python` on the PATH. To add the python to path see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609129/7871601) answer. Of course, you will be doing it for Python3 rather than 2, but the steps are the same. You can find another proper answer from the same topic.

Comment: Ok. The installer itself added python to PATH. It was a selectable option. I verified via entering "variables" into the Win10 search bar. C:\Python\Python39 is the only entry. When I check "python --version", it correctly displays "3.9.0". This still could be a path issue, I simply don't know. But I'm still unable to execute through the python_work folder. One thing is that if I let Python do the install, it tucks it way down the AppData pathway which makes calling it a chore, so that's why I manually installed Python directly to C:\. Could that be an issue?

Comment: If I let Python auto-install, it puts it behind C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39. My end-goal is to shorten this. That's why I put it directly on the C: drive with a manual install. Still, adding to to PATH was selected. I don't know why I'm getting downvoted. I'm reading straight from a beginners manual that told me how to download and install/config. I think moving the directory to C: is causing the issue, but I'm simply not that versed to know for sure. Thoughts?

Comment: My recommendation would be just try uninstalling python completely and then install [choco](https://chocolatey.org/install) (a package manager for windows) then execute your cmd as admin and then simply type `choco install python` it will automatically completes the all.